# Unable to change column data in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I've being trying to edit some data in one of my database columns, however no matter what I do the data remains the same even after uploading a completly new script with new data it remains in its original form.

The Table;

```
CREATE
TABLE EVENT
(
Location_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
Location    VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
) ;
ALTER TABLE EVENT ADD CONSTRAINT EVENT_PK PRIMARY KEY ( Location_ID ) ;
```

The data being inserted;

```
Insert into event (Location_ID,Location) values (001,'dundee');
Insert into event (Location_ID,Location) values (002,'Aberdeen');
Insert into event (Location_ID,Location) values (003,'Glasgow');
```

I have been attempting to change the Location ID numbers

Comment: If that doesn't help, examine the output of the script run results.

Comment: forgot to remove that when posting, fixed

Comment: This creates a table and inserts three rows. Are you dropping the table at some point? Otherwise, your `CREATE TABLE` statement is probably raising an error (since the event table already exists) and the rest of the script isn't running.